# How to stretch the image responsive to fill entire screen

Tags: html, css

I want to know how can I extend the image to the part ([) marked in black. This is my code (I'm trying to make it responsive):

```css
body {
  background: #aeddd5;
}

.main {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="main">
    <img src="./img/cf60903b8674148b9ab6ba194833fd2f_page-0001.jpg">
  </div>

</body>
```

What I have

[image: SS]

I want to have something like this:

[image: SS]

Comment: How do you want to rescale your image to fit the height? Do you want it to stretch? Do you want to resize with the same aspect ratio? More details have to be provided

Comment: Maybe [this post using viewport-percentage lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/how-to-make-a-div-100-height-of-the-browser-window). Flexbox can also work with the parent having `flex-direction: column;` and the child with `flex-grow: 1;` I think

Comment: yes, i want to resize with the same aspect ratio. I want the entire page to look like the second image

Comment: As the image is not having the required height as the screen , it is not possible to attain the desired result. The best thing what i can suggest is , you want to keep the aspect ratio same . So for that, just align the image to the center of the screen .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `height:100%` to `height:100vh` and add `object-fit:cover`

```css
body {
  background: #aeddd5;
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/1200">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to stretch the image for all screen views.

```css
body {
  background: #aeddd5;
}

.main {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  img[data-width="1024"] {
    height: 100vh;
  }
  img[data-width="1440"] {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP._HNl_Hk5V4UVNVikQTEvaQHaKb?pid=ImgDet&w=169&h=237&c=7" data-width="1024" data-height="768" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can stretch the image with the [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property, add `display: block` to the image for eliminate the excess space left by the images for being inline elements and declared a size coverting all the page with the [relative length units](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#n%C3%BAmeros_longitudes_y_porcentajes) `vh` and `vw`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <!-- Example image -->
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EzueaqPVgAEIPgd?format=jpg&name=large">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:-**

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Title</title>
<style>
body{
    background: #000000;
}
.main{
  max-width:900px;
  margin: auto;
}
img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  padding: 2%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.outborder{
    background: #aeddd5;
    padding: 1%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="outborder">
    <div class="main">
      <img src="./img/cf60903b8674148b9ab6ba194833fd2f_page-0001.jpg">   
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I guess this should work out for you. I just made another division for the aqua color and changed the body color to black. Added some padding & color to image background.